# What feature film had a giant metal military statue which moved, in front of a building?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to identify a SciFi feature film I saw perhaps five to ten years ago. The setting was on another planet, there was a dark theme, and there was a large building with a giant metal statue which was articulated - it moved. The statue had an imposing appearance, like a warrior or deity.

What keeps bringing this to mind are the large metal statues (shown below) at the [Macau Studio City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studio_City_(Macau)) Hotel and Casino. I believe the statue in the film looked quite similar, but that's all I've got.

[image] [image]

**above left:** From [leisureopportunities.co.uk](http://www.leisureopportunities.co.uk/images/HIGH5229_199812.jpg). **right:** From [tripadvisor.com](http://www.leisureopportunities.co.uk/images/HIGH5229_199812.jpg).

[image]

**above:** From [this tweet](https://twitter.com/aomentv/status/628787878198272001).

Comment: Seems very similar to the statue of Victor Von Doom from Fantastic Four

Comment: @Valorum I don't remember the statue being of any character in particular; I think it just appeared in the once to create a general mood or visual impression. Searching on that name I don't see anything that looks familliar either.

Comment: @Paulie_D wow that may be it! I did see it when it came out, and those helmets look very reminiscent. Was there a giant, imposing statue?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[**The Chronicles of Riddick**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0296572/) (2004) has statuary and other objects (spacecraft and weaponry) that feature such imagery.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]