# People running into the shadows to hide from killer sunlight, climbing scene

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the movie there are several people running into the shadows to hide from the sun that kills them. Whenever the sun hits them, they start to burn alive. I remember one scene where they are climbing on a mountain away from the sun that burns them.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and use that to [edit] further details into your question. Like when did you watch this? Live action? Animated? In English? Were they humans? Vampires? Aliens? Did it seem like it was set on Earth? Another planet? Different dimension?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Do you have a rough idea of the age of the film, when it came out, or when you saw it? That's image has been used in a number of films and stories, but the timing may help pin down which one it is. If it's fairly recent, the Chronicles of Riddick seems most likely, but if it has, say a 70s feel, that would point to something more like 'Quest.' (I don't even remember if 'Quest' had the scene, but it was part of the inspiration story, 'Frost and Fire'.)

Comment: It wasn't this, was it?
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667926/

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178929/what-feature-film-had-a-giant-metal-military-statue-which-moved-in-front-of-a-b

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this film as well. I used to think it was Total Recall, but I just re-watched it and there's no aspect of the plot that deals with burning sunlight and people running indoors/into the shadows to escape daybreak. Reading all the previous posts, no one has mentioned the movie I'm thinking about, which I believe is also the film the OP is referencing. I definitely remember a Total Recall-type vibe (80s/90s, on another planet, etc.), but for the life of me can not find any more information that would lead me to finding out what it is called.

Answer (score 81):

Could this be [*The Chronicles of Riddick*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0296572/)? There's a scene where various characters are climbing an outcrop. When the sun touches them, they burn horribly.

Comment: Escaping from an underground prison, on the aptly named planet Crematoria.

Comment: @dlatikay - I'm reasonably sure you mean "*prosaically* named planet"

Comment: by the time I wrote that, my physiology had already reasserted the need to process some solid nutrients for quite some time. I realized my inferior choice of phrase later, and stand corrected.

Answer (score 10):

This could be *The Mole People*, best known for its [appearance](https://mst3k.fandom.com/wiki/MST3K_803_-_The_Mole_People) during the eighth season of *Mystery Science Theater 3000*.  A group of mountaineering explorers (led by Shirley Temple's ex-husband, the extremely "moist" John Agar) discover an underground remnant of the ancient Sumerian civilization, where the people are so lacking in melanin that sunlight instantly sunburns them to death.  This is used as a form of ritual execution for criminals, and protagonists use the sunlight to protect them during their escape.  There is also a lot of climbing (prompting the riff:  "This movie is nothing but ropes and asses!").

The plot summary, [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mole_People):

> A narration by Dr. Frank Baxter, an English professor at the University of Southern California, explains the premise of the movie and its basis in reality. He briefly discusses the hollow earth theories of John Symmes and Cyrus Teed among others, and says that the movie is a fictionalized representation of these unorthodox theories.
>
> Archaeologists Dr. Roger Bentley and Dr. Jud Bellamin find a race of Sumerian albinos living deep under the Earth. They keep mutant humanoid mole men as their slaves to harvest mushrooms, which serve as their primary food source. The Sumerian albinos' ancestors relocated into the subterranean after cataclysmic floods in ancient Mesopotamia. They believe the men are messengers of Ishtar, their goddess. Whenever their population increases, they sacrifice old people to the Eye of Ishtar. These people have lived underground for so long that they are weakened by bright light which the archaeologists brought in the form of a flashlight. However, there is one girl named Adad who has natural Caucasian skin who is disdained by the others since she has the "mark of darkness."
>
> When one of the archaeologists is killed by a mole person, Elinu, the High Priest, realizes they are not gods. He orders their capture and takes the flashlight to control the Mole People, not knowing it is depleted. The archaeologists are then sent to the Eye of Ishtar just as the Mole People rebel. Adad goes to the Eye only to realize it is really natural light coming from the surface and that the men had survived. They then climb to the surface. Unfortunately, Adad dies after reaching the surface when an earthquake causes a column to fall over and crush her.

Answer (score 8):

Could this be *[Missile to the Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053072/)* as per [Movie about the sun being too hot it burned and kill very fast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96780/movie-about-the-sun-being-too-hot-it-burned-and-kill-very-fast)?

> .... Right near the end the lunar astronauts are trying to evade "rock men" while staying in the shadows.  One astronaut, escaped convict stowaway Gary, refuses to drop the bags of diamonds he has collected.  With the extra weight he is not quick enough to manage.

The film has men climbing up a rock face, and having to stay in the shadows, or else they will be burned, as seen in the case of Gary.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to other answers this could be any number of vampire films, but it makes me think in particular of 1987's Near Dark, in which the protagonist is a vampire and hiding in shadows / burning in sunlight is a recurring theme.

Trailer:

Answer (score 2):

This reminded me of the Ray Bradbury story [Frost and Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_(short_story)), which was made into a film, [Quest](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086162/), in 1984.

Comment: You should describe the scene from the movie that matches the details from the question.

Comment: @DavidW: I haven't seen the movie.

Answer (score 0):

Might the answer be the movie "Core", in which the earth loses its protective magnetic field?

Comment: People burn but there's no climbing scene.

Comment: I've seen *The Core*, and it's definitely not the film OP is looking for.

Comment: @F1Krazy - I don't think it's the film that *anyone* is looking for.